# Update-Database using Simple Injector, without services.AddDbContext<>()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-5, simple-injector

.NET Core 3.1, EF Core 5.0 preview 6.

I am using [Simple Injector 5.0](https://simpleinjector.org/) to register `IMyContextFactory` (I'm not using `services.AddDbContext<>()`).

My `MyContext` have all constructors set to private because I use ContextFactory without tenantId and sometimes with few different tenantIds at one request, so I make sure that everyone will use `IMyContextFactory` injection instead of `MyContext` and to prevent creating `new MyContext()` in controllers etc.

But how to do `Update-Database`?

1. While I do `Update-Database` I always have error `Login failed for user ''.`, but I can run and connect to database from my WebAPI project without any problem (my ConnectionString is good).
2. I was able to apply migration at runtime, but I have to add `services.AddDbContext<MyContext>()`, make constructors for `MyContext` as public and get this context from `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>()` in Program.cs, because my `IMyContextFactory` was not inside `ServiceProvider`. (via https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=vs#apply-migrations-at-runtime)

How to achieve that only with Simple Injector?

Comment: Have you tried [design-time DbContext factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory)? I'm not sure if `Update-Database` uses it, but maybe it could.

Comment: Yes I was already implemented it. But yes, `Update-Database` uses it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is to add ConnectionString to your `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implementation:

```
// Fix for "Unable to create an object of type 'MyContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728" error while creating migration
public class MyContextDesignFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    private string _appsettingsPath = "./../Path/To/ProjectWithAppsettingsJSON";

    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        // In 90% we don't have ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT here, so set fallback to Development
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development";

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), _appsettingsPath))
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();

        Console.WriteLine($"Default ConnectionString comes from appsettings file.{Environment.NewLine}You can override it by using `dotnet ef database update --connection MyConnectionString`");

        // Use ConnectionString from appsettings inside WebAPI to fix `Update-Database` command from Package Manager Console
        // We still can override ConnectionString by `dotnet ef database update --connection MyConnectionString`
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(config["ConnectionString"]);

        return MyContext.MyContextFactory.GetMyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this is to install [Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) and to update database from it.

Note: Disable all private NuGet repositories in Visual Studio and install tool in Package Manager Console:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.0-preview.6.20312.4
```

Now you can enable your private NuGet feeds in Visual Studio.

Then, go to folder, where your context and configuration is and:

```
dotnet ef database update --connection "Your=Connection;String"
```

You can also change Connection String using `Update-Database`:

```
Update-Database -connection "Your=Connection;String"
```

But this is workaround. I'm still asking you for solution "inside" Visual Studio IDE, without installing additional CMD tools